# How do I retrieve all elements from a form?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get all the elments in a form. I can do that using `document.getElementById('form').elements` but it returns extra properties (see below) that I don't want. How do I "remove" it?

The code:

```
var result = document.getElementById('form').elements;
for(var key in result)
{
  console.log(key, ' = ', result[key]);
}
```

Here's the ouput:

```
0 = <input id="A" type="text" name="A" value="a">
1 = <input id="B" type="text" name="B" value="b">
2 = <input type="checkbox" name="C">
namedItem = namedItem()
item = item()
@@iterator = @@iterator()
length = 3
```

I want only the HTML elements, i.e, value of 0, 1, and 2. Like this:

```
0 = <input id="A" type="text" name="A" value="a">
1 = <input id="B" type="text" name="B" value="b">
2 = <input type="checkbox" name="C">
```

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lt6xrb8/1/)

I know that a simple test like this:

```
if(!isNumber(key))
        continue;
```

will do the job fine but I'm looking for a "elegant" solution and will use this test if there are no any.

Comment: You can filter the results

Comment: @NetaMeta: With something like `isNumber(key)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest way:

```
var result = document.getElementById('form').elements;
console.log(result);

for(var key in result)
{
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(key))
        console.log(key, ' = ', result[key]);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Lt6xrb8/2/

Answer (score 1):

as per my opinion the great way of doing this is.

```
if(!isNumber(key))
    continue;
```

another way is checking for node name.

```
var result = document.getElementById('form').elements;
for(var key in result)
{
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(key))
  console.log(key, ' = ', result[key]);

}
```

jsfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/v9vb3t26/

Comment: ravi what happened if its not an input and its a select ? you now have to add select, or textarea ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this cool way

```js
 var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
    //Extract Each Element Value
    for (var i = 0; i < myForm.elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(myForm.elements[i].value);
    }
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="User" value="Arsalan"/>
        <input type="password" name="pass" value="123"/>
        <input type="number" name="age" value="24"/>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="johndoe@test.com"/>
        <textarea name="message">Enter Your Message Her</textarea>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
var result = document.getElementById('form').elements;
console.log(result);

for(var key in result)
{
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(key))
        console.log(key, ' = ', result[key]);

}
```